# Why is each chord of a conic having a unique midpoint corresponding to it? (Excluding centre of symmetries)

Tags: conic-sections

If you have a conic $C(x,y)$ then by homogenization, we find the tangent line at the point $(x,y)$ to be $L(x,y,X,Y,Z=1)=\frac{\partial C}{\partial x} X + \frac{\partial C}{\partial y} Y + \frac{\partial C}{\partial Z}=0$, now let $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\alpha',\beta')$ be two distinct point on the conic and $(l,n)$ their midpoint, then it turns out that:

$$C(l,n)= L(l,n,X,Y,Z=1)$$

To be the equation of chord of point $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\alpha',\beta')$ but is there any way to prove that any two points on a conic have a unique midpoint?

I find the uniqueness to be quite a crazy result, since it associates each chord on the conic to a point and hence want a bit more insight on it.

---

#### Observation:

The equation fails if you take a point on center of symmetery of the conic eg: center of circle, there are many points mapping to the same mid point.. for sake of original question, leave this. But, I am also curious to how this equation breaks down from algebraic point of view as well.

**Interesting corollaries:**

For a unit circle parameterized as $(\cos t,\sin t)$ , it turns out that if we have four points on the circle $\alpha,\beta,\gamma, \delta$, and we consider MP point corresponding to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and also point corresponding to $\gamma$ and $\delta$, then the equation:

$$ \cos \alpha + \cos \beta = \cos \gamma + \cos \delta$$

Has no solution unless the angles other than the case where angles are diametrically opposite i.e: different by  $\pm \pi$. Similar result for $\sin$.

**The equation  of tangent** : If we let $(l,n)$ be a point on the conic, we recover equation of tangent of conic at a point.

---

Please note, it is the partial derivatives which are function of $(x,y)$ in the equation of line.

Examples of usage :  [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4218853/688539)

Homogenization can be found in an [old calculus book by Joseph Edwards](https://archive.org/details/differentialcal03edwagoog/page/n126/mode/1up)

Comment: Are you talking about points of contact from an external point or any two pairs of points on the conic having unique midpoint?

Comment: The equation relates to the chord line through mid point, so any pair of point-> a unique mid point( apprently)-> a unique chord @MathLover

Comment: yes now the question seems complete (after you added the observation)

Comment: Note that at the center of the circle, the gradient of $C$ vanishes.

Comment: This property follows from a well-known fact: all parallel chords of a conic have their midpoints aligned along a diameter passing through the center (or parallel to the axis in the case of a parabola). Tangents at the endpoints of the diameter are also parallel to the chords. Search "[conjugate diameters of a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_diameters)" to find a variety of proofs.

Answer (score 1):

If point $P$ is within a conic section (but different from its centre) then there is a unique chord having $P$ as midpoint.

Proof. Join $P$ with the centre of the conic (or draw the line through $P$ parallel to the axis, in the case of a parabola) and produce that line (if needed) to meet the conic at $A$. By the properties of [conjugate diameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_diameters), the chord through $P$ parallel to the tangent at $A$ is the unique chord having midpoint $P$.

For a hyperbola, this also works if $P$ is outside the hyperbola (but not on an asymptote), provided we also consider the conjugate hyperbola.

Comment: And the chord eq is given by $T=S_1$